# Removing blank element

Tags: javascript, php, null, indexing, element

I tried doing this myself but so far I am only able to disable blank elements in a loop I am doing the following:

```
 echo "\t\t\tdocument.choice.field1.options[index].disabled=true;\n";
```

The above disables these lines but then I tried to make it null to remove the blank row/element but it doesn't work, the element shows up as a null, I need to completely remove it.

```
 echo "\t\t\tdocument.choice.field1.options[index]=null;\n";
```

Comment: Why not just do an "if not null" check and only echo it the condition is met?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might be looking for is [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild)

Your code would look something like

```
document.choice.field1.removeChild(document.choice.field1.options[index])
```

Comment: one question I had, I tried this and it does work but at times I seem to get "document.choice.field1.options is null or not an object", don't know why?